# HoverIntent & Superfish Delay not working

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting the delay parameter working for HoverIntent & Superfish for a WordPress site. The website found here: http://bit.ly/MJ8KT6 is fading in wonderfully but simply not providing the delay on mouseout using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// initialise plugins
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('ul#menu-primary-navigation').superfish({
     delay:600
    });
});

</script>
```

I've tried setting **disableHI: false** to ensure that HoverIntent was not disabled by any chance. Being a WordPress site I also checked the script was being correctly loaded using wp_enqueue_script but again to no avail. The code works fine in a HTML file so it has to be something to do with WordPress. I'm wondering whether it's something I have overlooked. Any feedback greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with WordPress and everything to do with your CSS definitions. (So it will be closed as off-topic above). But since you still need an answer ...

In your default stylesheet, you define the list elements containing your sub-menus as:

```
.menu ul li ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999em;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 200px;
}
```

This pushes the menus entirely off the screen, which is fine.  But you then override the `left: -9999em;` declaration with a hover pseudo-state:

```
.menu ul li:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}
```

Even without Superfish installed, this combination of CSS will make the sub-menu appear and disappear on the screen when you hover over the main menu item.  Unfortunately, it also means that the menu will disappear immediately when you stop hovering.  It is still being hidden by Superfish ... it's just not on the screen any longer.

If you simply remove the `left: -9999em;` declaration from your CSS, the menu will stay visible when you mouse off the screen until the timer reaches the set delay ... then it disappears.

Comment: Hi @EAMann, thank you so much for this. I did read another post which mentioned this could be a CSS issue & I did actually look at that piece of styling but for some reason it didn't twig. Thanks again ;)